# Echo displaying the SQL command as well as the result

Tags: sql, bash

I have a variable which is finding the latest id from a db table, i am then looking to append the result of this query to the middle of another variable, this is because each time the script is ran it needs to create a new table incrementing from the previous id

```
TABLE_NUMBER=$(mysql -u $2 $3 -h $4 -e "SELECT Max(Id)+1 FROM TableofInterest;" db_name)
echo "table number is"
echo $TABLE_NUMBER

LATESTID="Interest_${TABLE_NUMBER}_Map"

echo $LATESTID
```

The above displays the result as:

```
 Thu  4 Aug 2022 15:08:57 UTC
running the script
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
table number is
Max(Id)+1 3
Interest_Max(Id)+1 3_Map
```

I was wanting it to display just the number, not the Max(id)+1

It should display `Interest_3_Map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

`TABLE_NUMBER=$(mysql -u $2 $3 -h $4 -e "SELECT Max(Id)+1 FROM TableofInterest;" db_name | sed -n 2p)`

Most flavors of SQL print the output of commands as a table with a header labeling each column. If you don't want that header then you can filter the output to remove it. In this case `sed -n 2p` prints only the second line of output which should be the result you care about.

Comment: you are a hero, that worked, thanks!

Comment: @user3296793 you should also be able to use the `-sN` switch with mysql client to suppress the column header and table outline in the query output:  `TABLE_NUMBER=$(mysql -sN -u $2 $3 -h $4 -e "SELECT Max(Id)+1 FROM TableofInterest;" db_name)